# Take an ActiveRecord model that can accept nested attributes for another model, and update it individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-attributes

### tl;dr

Can you *create* two ActiveRecord models using nested attributes, but *update* them individually?

### Longer Version

I am working on a SaaS application in which I have (among other things) two models, an Account model and a User model.

Using Rails 4.0.3 & Ruby: 2.1.1

#### Account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'

  validates :owner, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner, :update_only => true
```

#### User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :registerable

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true
```

An Account accepts nested attributes for a User.  When someone signs up for the app, they create both their Account and their User profile at the same time (a single form with nested attributes).

While this is an ideal user flow for signing up for the site, I would like for a User to be able to update their Account information separately from updating their User information.  I have set up Account#edit and Account#update actions, as well as an edit view (see code below):

#### AccountsController

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  def edit
    @account = current_account
  end

  def update
    @account = current_account
    if @account.update_attributes(account_params)
      redirect_to settings_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def account_params
        params.require(:account).permit(:firm_name,
                                    :street_address,
                                    :city,
                                    :state,
                                    :zip_code,
                                    :phone,
                                    :subdomain,
                                    owner_attributes: [ :first_name, 
                                                        :last_name, 
                                                        :email, 
                                                        :password, 
                                                        :password_confirmation])
    end
end
```

#### views/accounts/edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit Account Info</h2>
  <%= simple_form_for @account do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :firm_name %>
    <%= f.input :street_address %>
    <%= f.input :city %>
    <%= f.input :state %>
    <%= f.input :zip_code %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
```

When a User attempts to update their Account using this form, the update fails because the presence validation for the owner's (the User's) password fails.  In AccountsController#update, if you check the error messages after line 42, you will see:

```
Owner's password can't be blank
```

What I would like to know is this - is there a way to *create* two models using nested attributes, but *update* them separately?  I have spent several hours researching this issue and not found an analogous situation described nor a true solution to the problem.  To be clear, I want to update *only* the Account (the parent model), not the User.

Some things that have been tried:

- changing the strong params for accounts
- using AR's :inverse_of for the Account and User models
- including the User's password in the params (in the proper, nested
  way, just like during Account/User creation)

I do have a partial solution in place, though not an ideal one - it involves bypassing the password validations specifically for the AccountsController#update action.

Any tips or advice would be welcome!  Thank you.

Comment: does `accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner, :update_only => true` work for you? why do it in the `child` model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to update the account without updating the user. A couple of points before we hopefully get to a solution:

You shouldn't need to do these validations in user, because Devise will take care of them automatically:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true
```

If you are looking to update just the account in this controller, you should remove anything about the owner_attributes from the params. Like this:

```
def account_params
  params.require(:account).permit(
    :firm_name, :street_address, :city, :state, :zip_code, :phone, :subdomain
  )
end
```

I think what's happening is that there are empty params getting passed into nested_attributes_for, which try to update owner, but Devise is blocking that because by default you can't update Devise User attributes without a password:

[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Redefining account_params (for #update, at least) is one of the things that we tried but oddly it had no effect.  The same error message (Owner password can't be blank) gets added to the @account object, even when @account.update_attributes(account_params) is called with account_params defined like you mentioned in your answer.